# Combine Ranking matrix of User based and Item based

Tags: r, recommender-system

I am doing 1 **assignment on Recommendation in R using RecommenderLab** package. The data I have is of different customers.
Each customer have its Demographic information like Age, Gender, Education, Income, with this I also have is transaction details. like product bought.

```
Cust_No Age Gender Education Income Product1 Product2 Product3 
  1     25   M     Post_Grad  30K    Beer    Bread   Butter
```

So the confusion is first 4 features(Age Gender Education Income) are of **User based** and last 3(Product1 Product2 Product3)  are **Item based**. How to create ***ranking matrix and combine both*** and how to pass it to Recommendation model. Please Help me out.